# Update packages in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R Shiny app I've had zero problems with for about a year now. Suddenly it isn't working ("disconnected from server"), and I discovered that the issue seems to be one of the packages (`rdrop2`) the app depends on was recently updated. When i run the app off my desktop after reinstalling rdrop2 the app runs fine.

Is there a way to have R Shiny install the latest version of a package? I tried including `install.packages("rdrop2")` in my code but to no avail.

Comment: I don't see any dependecies between `rdrop` and `shiny`, so forcing compatibility via the `DESCRIPTION` file (which would be the usual way to do this) is not possible. You can however check the version of `rdrop2` when your app starts and throw an error if the version is not new enough.

Comment: If your app is hosted on a server, you will have to make sure the package is available for the user running the app. Normally, this user is called `shiny`. See [here](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#run_as).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to detect problems like this is to setup [automated tests in Rshiny](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/testing-shiny-applications-with-shinytest/) with continuous integration. You still need to install the package manually, but at least you can get a notification if the application does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem comes from the fact that the builtin credentials in the package expired. I had the same problem. A subsequent update updated the default credentials in the package but you had to re-authorize them. My advice is to bite the bullet and create your own app credentials.